# Where can I find the function definition of route and resource?

Tags: ember.js

Where are the functions *route()* and *resource()*, from the following snippet, defined?

I would like read their description.

```js
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.route('about');
  this.resource('article');
});
```

Comment: from the source code: 
this.resource() is deprecated. Use this.route(\'name\', { resetNamespace: true }, function () {}) instead.

Comment: from the source code: 
" route(name, options, callback) " OR
" route(name, callback) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are methods on an internal object called "DSL" used for building routing tables. This is the context object with which `Ember.Router` calls the function passed to `map`. You don't need to worry about them. The relevant source code is [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/49d58530527c9025b4bafe4f937b0c78cfe3818e/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/dsl.js). It's not commented, so you're out of luck in terms of reading their descriptions, other than what's in the Ember guides and API docs, which is very little, but then again, they're pretty simple.

The guides are coy about this object:

> When calling map, you should pass a function that will be invoked with the value `this` set to an *object which you can use* to create routes and resources.

The "object which you can use" being referred to is the DSL.